# How to display Mongoose Schema onto EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I have a MongoDB database with a collection of data that I imported that I need to display onto an EJS through localhost. I have already created the schema. How do I get it to display onto my EJS file? I'm extremely new and had to start late in this course so I'm very behind and confused. I don't need any type of CRUD. I'm not confident in what I have currently, so any advice, help, and resources would be very much appreciated!

My App.js

```
var app = require("express")(); 
var bodyparser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/quake", {useNewUrlParser: true});

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
});

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var quakeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  time : String,
  lattitude : String,
  longitude : String,
  depth : String,
  mag : String,
  magType : String,
  nst : String, 
  gap : String,
  dmin : String,
  rms : String,
  net : String,
  id : String,
  updated : String,
  place : String,
  horizontal :String,
  depthError: String,
  magError : String, 
  magNst : String,
  locationSource : String,
  magSource : String
},{
  collection : 'februaryQuakes'
}); 

var quakeTable = mongoose.model('quakeDisplay', quakeSchema);
```

My index.ejs

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>EarthQuake Homework
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Get Data from DB</h1>

<table class ="items">
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Lattitude</th>
        <th>Longitude</th>
        <th>Depth</th>
        <th>Mag</th>
        <th>Mag Type</th>
        <th>NST</th>
        <th>GAP</th>
        <th>DMIN</th>
        <th>RMS</th>
        <th>NET</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Updated</th>
        <th>Place</th>
        <th>Horizontal</th>
        <th>Depth Error</th>
        <th>Mag Error</th>
        <th>MAG NST</th>
        <th>Location Source</th>
        <th>MagSource</th>
    </tr>
    <% details.forEach(function(item){ %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= items.time%></td>
        <td><%= items.lattitude %></td>
        <td><%= items.longitude%></td>
        <td><%= items.depth %></td>
        <td><%= items.mag%></td>
        <td><%= items.magType%></td>
        <td><%= items.nst%></td>
        <td><%= items.gap%></td>
        <td><%= items.dmin%></td>
        <td><%= items.rms%></td>
        <td><%= items.net%></td>
        <td><%= items.id%></td>
        <td><%= items.updated%></td>
        <td><%= items.place%></td>
        <td><%= items.horizontal%></td>
        <td><%= items.depthError%></td>
        <td><%= items.magError%></td>
        <td><%= items.magNst%></td>
        <td><%= items.locationSource%></td>
        <td><%= items.magSource%></td>
    </tr>
    <% }) %>
    </table>
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `forEach` function uses `item` but in your `<td>`s you have `items.x` There's also no `app.get()` or similar in your app to actually render a view in response to a request.

Answer (score 0):

To get your data injected into the EJS template, you need to query for the data from MongoDB database, then render the template with the data. So, you should have a route like this in your `app.js`:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    // Query for the data from MongoDB
    const data = await quakeTable.find({}); 

    // Render the template with the data. You might need to change the path to 
    // the EJS file here depending on your file structure
    res.render('index', { details: data }); 
});
```

Whenever you visit `http://localhost:<port>/`, where  is the port number your application is running, the HTML should be rendered with the data from the DB.